# How to extract the zerolog event fields in the hook

Tags: azure, go, azure-application-insights, distributed-tracing, zerolog

I wrote a code for integrating Azure app insights with Zerolog, one thing I'm not sure about is how to get the event fields inside the hook function so I can publish the data fields into the Azure app insights custom properties field or is there any other cleaner way to achieve this.

Does anyone think zerolog should expose a function to get the fields?

```
package zeroappinsights

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Go/appinsights"
    "github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Go/appinsights/contracts"
    "github.com/rs/zerolog"
    "github.com/rs/zerolog/log"

    "github.com/org/package/constants"
    "github.com/org/package/models"
)

var levelMap = map[zerolog.Level]contracts.SeverityLevel{
    zerolog.ErrorLevel: contracts.Error,
    zerolog.InfoLevel:  contracts.Information,
    zerolog.DebugLevel: contracts.Verbose,
    zerolog.FatalLevel: contracts.Critical,
    zerolog.WarnLevel:  contracts.Warning,
}

var appInsightsProperties = []string{
    contracts.OperationId,
    contracts.OperationParentId,
    contracts.UserId,
    contracts.SessionId,
}

type TracingHook struct {
    env             constants.Environment
    telemetryClient appinsights.TelemetryClient
    file            *os.File
    eventsMap       map[string]string
}

func NewAITracing(serviceName, instrumentationKey string, env constants.Environment, eventsMap map[string]string) *TracingHook {
    client := appinsights.NewTelemetryClient(instrumentationKey)
    client.Context().Tags.Cloud().SetRole(serviceName)
    if env.IsLocal() {
        file, err := os.OpenFile(serviceName+".log", os.O_CREATE, 0644)
        if err != nil {
            return nil
        }

        return &TracingHook{
            telemetryClient: client,
            file:            file,
            env:             constants.Local,
        }
    }
    return &TracingHook{
        telemetryClient: client,
        file:            nil,
        env:             env,
        eventsMap:       eventsMap,
    }
}

func (h *TracingHook) Run(e *zerolog.Event, level zerolog.Level, msg string) {
    ctx := e.GetCtx()
    if appinsightsLevel, ok := levelMap[level]; ok {
        trace := appinsights.NewTraceTelemetry(msg, appinsightsLevel)
        for _, property := range appInsightsProperties {
            trace.Tags[property] = ctx.Value(property).(string)
        } 
        //I want to add more properties from the event to trace.Properties
        trace.Timestamp = time.Now().UTC()
        if h.env.IsLocal() {
            // Marshal the request into a JSON byte slice
            traceJSON, err := json.Marshal(trace)
            if err != nil {
                log.Printf("error marshaling request: %v", err)
                return
            }
            if _, err = h.file.Write(append(traceJSON, '\n')); err != nil {
                log.Printf("error occurred while writing to file: %v", err)
                return
            }
        } else {
            go h.telemetryClient.Track(trace)
        }
    }

}

func (h *TracingHook) LoggingMiddleware(logger zerolog.Logger) func(c *gin.Context) {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        startTime := time.Now().UTC()
        telemetry := appinsights.NewEventTelemetry(h.eventsMap[c.Request.URL.Path])
        h.telemetryClient.Track(telemetry)
        operationID := telemetry.Tags[contracts.OperationId]
        operationParentID := telemetry.Tags[contracts.OperationParentId]
        userID := telemetry.Tags[contracts.UserId]
        sessionID := telemetry.Tags[contracts.SessionId]

        if value, exists := c.Get("userProfile"); exists {
            profile := value.(models.UserProfile)
            userID = profile.ID
            sessionID = c.Request.Header.Get(constants.Session)
        }

        values := []string{operationID, operationParentID, userID, sessionID}

        ctx := c.Request.Context()
        for i, key := range appInsightsProperties {
            ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, key, values[i])
        }
        loggerContext := logger.WithContext(ctx)
        c.Set("loggerCtx", loggerContext)
        c.Next()

        duration := time.Since(startTime)
        request := appinsights.NewRequestTelemetry(c.Request.Method, c.Request.URL.Path, duration, http.StatusText(c.Writer.Status()))
        request.Timestamp = time.Now().UTC()
        tags := request.Tags
        tags[contracts.OperationId] = operationID
        tags[contracts.OperationParentId] = operationParentID
        tags[contracts.UserId] = userID
        tags[contracts.SessionId] = sessionID
        request.Tags = tags

        if h.env.IsLocal() {
            // Marshal the request into a JSON byte slice
            requestJSON, err := json.Marshal(request)
            if err != nil {
                log.Printf("error marshaling request: %v", err)
                return
            }
            if _, err = h.file.Write(append(requestJSON, '\n')); err != nil {
                log.Printf("error occurred while writing to file: %v", err)
                return
            }
            return
        }
        h.telemetryClient.Track(request)
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a field like `eventFields map[string]interface{}` to the `TracingHook` struct. by this you can store additional fields from the event that you want to include in the trace and  can pass the `eventsMap` as well as an empty map for `eventFields` while creating the  new instance of TracingHook.

Answer (score 1):

Below you can see the hook function that extracts the relevant information from the `Zerolog` event and add it to the Application Insights telemetry properties.

- Integrate Azure Application Insights with Zerolog and capture custom properties

**Code:**

```golang
package zeroappinsights

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Go/appinsights"
    "github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Go/appinsights/contracts"
    "github.com/rs/zerolog"
    "github.com/rs/zerolog/log"

    "github.com/org/package/constants"
    "github.com/org/package/models"
)

var levelMap = map[zerolog.Level]contracts.SeverityLevel{
    zerolog.ErrorLevel: contracts.Error,
    zerolog.InfoLevel:  contracts.Information,
    zerolog.DebugLevel: contracts.Verbose,
    zerolog.FatalLevel: contracts.Critical,
    zerolog.WarnLevel:  contracts.Warning,
}

var appInsightsProperties = []string{
    contracts.OperationId,
    contracts.OperationParentId,
    contracts.UserId,
    contracts.SessionId,
}

// ApplicationInsightsHook is a Zerolog hook that sends log entries to Application Insights
type ApplicationInsightsHook struct {
    client appinsights.TelemetryClient
}

// NewApplicationInsightsHook creates a new ApplicationInsightsHook
func NewApplicationInsightsHook(instrumentationKey string) *ApplicationInsightsHook {
    client := appinsights.NewTelemetryClient(instrumentationKey)
    return &ApplicationInsightsHook{client: client}
}

// Fire is called when a log event is fired.
func (hook *ApplicationInsightsHook) Fire(e *zerolog.Event) error {
    severity, ok := levelMap[e.Level()]
    if !ok {
        severity = contracts.Verbose
    }

    telemetry := appinsights.NewTraceTelemetry(e.Message().String(), severity)

    // Add custom properties
    e.Fields(func(key string, value interface{}) {
        telemetry.Properties[key] = fmt.Sprintf("%v", value)
    })

    // Add predefined properties
    for _, prop := range appInsightsProperties {
        if value, ok := e.Context[prop].(string); ok {
            telemetry.Properties[prop] = value
        }
    }

    hook.client.Track(telemetry)

    return nil
}

// Levels returns the log levels to enable for this hook.
func (hook *ApplicationInsightsHook) Levels() []zerolog.Level {
    return []zerolog.Level{
        zerolog.PanicLevel,
        zerolog.FatalLevel,
        zerolog.ErrorLevel,
        zerolog.WarnLevel,
        zerolog.InfoLevel,
        zerolog.DebugLevel,
    }
}

// SetLogger sets the logger for the hook.
func (hook *ApplicationInsightsHook) SetLogger(logger *zerolog.Logger) {
    *logger = logger.Hook(hook)
}

// Usage:
func main() {
    // Initialize the Application Insights hook
    aiHook := NewApplicationInsightsHook("your-instrumentation-key")

    // Create a Zerolog logger and set the hook
    logger := zerolog.New(os.Stdout).With().Timestamp().Logger()
    aiHook.SetLogger(&logger)

    // Use the logger as usual
    logger.Info().Str("customField", "customValue").Msg("Log message")
}
```

- By this `ApplicationInsightsHook` struct is created and it implementing the `zerolog.Hook` interface.
- The `Fire` method is called when a log event is fired, and it extracts relevant information from the Zerolog event, including custom fields, and adds them to the Application Insights telemetry.

[image]

[image]